# How can I force VS Code to run Python processes in a fresh terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code (VSCodium to be specific), when I click on "Run Python file in terminal" - the little green arrow top right - the same terminal is used for multiple processes. I'd like to run multiple Python processes in parallel. Currently, the only way is to open a new terminal inside VS Code and run the desired file manually by entering its path. Is it possible to reconfigure the "Run" button so that a new terminal will be opened where the current file that's open in the editor gets started?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, if you want to automatically open multiple new terminals, it is recommended that you set the way of result output: set `"console": "externalTerminal",` in the "`launch.json`" file in the "`.vscode`" folder. After setting, the result of each debugging will be automatically output in a new cmd window.

[image]

Update:

For setting the python run button ("Run python file in terminal"), so that the code can be automatically synchronized to run in different terminals. Currently, VSCode does not support this function. The available method is to manually enter the path of the script as you said.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the `.vscode` folder supposed to be located? There is a `.vscode-oss` folder in my Home directory but it does not contain a `launch.json`. I created one, to no effect.

Comment: @smcs You could use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+p", and then enter "Debug:Open launch.json". You could also click the setting icon (open launch.json) next to "Python: Current File" on the Debug page.  You can refer to it: [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_additional-configurations)

Comment: Thanks. It seems the `launch.json` is only for debugging--I'd like to run the processes normally. When starting a debug session, an external terminal is opened, so that part works.. but after starting one process, I can't start the same file again, nothing happens when I select "Start debugging...".

Comment: @smcs Could you describe it in detail? Can this process run successfully? I try to debug a process repeatedly and they can open new terminals each.

Comment: These were my steps: 1) Open the Python file in editor 2) Select the "Run" view in the leftmost pane 3) On top of the "Run" view, there is a green arrow next to the current debug configuration--clicking it starts debugging and opens an external terminal 4) Clicking the green arrow again does nothing.

Comment: I just noticed that I can start another debug session after the first one has finished running. This, I believe, is what happened in your example screenshot--all that script did was print "123", but I would like to run two processes that each take minutes in parallel.

Comment: @smcs Yes, if you want to run synchronously, it cannot automatically open multiple terminals at the same time. They will run in a default terminal one by one to prevent confusion caused by too many terminals. I have submitted this question and we look forward to the realization of this feature. Thank you very much for your feedback. Github link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094