# VS Code : Run python File in other terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when I launch a python process, the terminal is busy running it.
If I then want to run a new python process (By running "Run python File in Terminal") then it just queues it up in the same terminal.

I am happy to manually create a new terminal, and put it in focus, but when I select "Run python File in Terminal" then VS Code automatically switches to the old one, and so does not run the code.

How can I solve that?

(Note that I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995563/how-can-i-force-vs-code-to-run-python-processes-in-a-fresh-terminal), but it is not the same because I do not want to automatically spawn a new terminal - the new terminal is already there)

Comment: At present, it can only be run manually in the new terminal by using "python fileName.py". This request is still open on github. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out. I am surprised this request has not been implemented, as this seems a fairly important feature.